# How to add textview in actionbar instead of application name with image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to add Textview with image like below image instead of application name:

[image]

I dont want to remove menu image . i just want to remove applicatoin name from actionbar and put this kind of textview and on that click i want to show toast.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

> You can make your own app bar xml. Include the app bar where you want to show using include tag. Don't forget to define your theme as NoActionBar in styles.

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Here the toolbar xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/header_color"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />



    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewNotification" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/tab_bar_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewlogin" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar(); //get the actionbar

action.setCustomView(R.layout.your_bar);//add the custom view
action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the title
```

after it , make layout with what you wants like textView, imageVie etc.. 
Hope helped u :D